# Is it possible to customize sankey node width in plotly?

Tags: plotly

I've been trying to modify sankey default node width with no results.

Thanks!

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: @DanielaDiaz Please tell us what you have tried then. And provide a runnable code snippet and a proper data sample.